# ListView separators using a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem, separator

I have a ListView which is populated using a CursorAdapter.  I'd also like to have some separators in my ListView.  I have accomplished this with an ArrayAdapter, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with a CursorAdapter.  Are there any strategies for doing so?  Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some examples:
http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html

Projects:
http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Best,

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'll have a look

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing.  The layout for every list item contains a LinearLayout which acts as a separator, but some contraint determines whether you hide or show the LinearLayout.  I don't think the constraint is particularly important other than it works, but the separator is ultimately present in every item.  Neat idea.  I think I will try it out.  Thanks again

Comment: The link is for a private blog which cannot be viewed. :(

Comment: Update to new samples because of problems with the original one. Tks

Answer (score 1):

Also this one: http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/, here section header is "sticky" at the top of the list which makes it really nice.

Comment: Should have posted your [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148376/separators-in-listview)'s link here rather than pasting it completely