# "Separators" in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have an `ArrayAdapter` which is hooked up to my `ListView`. I really like the "separators" feature in the Evernote Android application, where they separate items using a datestamp:

[image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2] [image: screenshot 3] [image]

I assume what they're doing is having a view immediately above the list which is set to the value of the current separator, as you can see in the screenshots. (As you scroll past a separator, the text at the top is set to the value of the current separator, ie "January 2011") How would I actually insert the separators into my `ListView`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A separator is simply a disabled list item, just have your `Adapter` return the separator where it should be. Seems like [`SectionIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) could help.

Answer (score 4):

And here is one which does exactly this : https://github.com/Polidea/android-section-list with transparent section header sticky at the top of the list (similar to iOS section list which comes out of the box there).

Answer (score 1):

We're on our own on this one.

I made my own ListView with headers for one of my apps: [Dhammapada](https://github.com/appamatto/dhammapada-android) (look for HeadingAdapter and associated classes)

Answer (score 0):

set two layouts on a single screen one above other... 
then add scroll to layout which is below... 
then add list view in d second half layout ... fix it up and deploy ur sh$T and its done !!
Note : dont add scroll in main layout .. just on layout which is underneath :p

eg:-

```
<LL1 
bla bla
>

<LL2 bla bla>
</LL2>

<LL3 scroll bla bla>
<ListView bla bla>
</ListView> 

</LL3>

</LL1>
```