# Showing headers in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a database that is implemented in a ListView.
I want to section the ListView and add headers (separators). What I mean is, that I have many cities, and I want to group them by country with seperators.
Here is the class, which I think, has something to do with headers:

```
String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products);
        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {

            /*  // selected item 
              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);*/
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148376/separators-in-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separator is basically a just a custom list item. You need to override the adapter to return a disabled list item where you want the headers to be.

For your instance, you could add the separators in the string arrays at the right position and make the following adjustments to a custom adapter:

- Override getViewTypeCount() to return 2, for the separator and the list item
- Override getItemViewType() to return 0 for regular list items and 1 for separators
- Override getView() and have it properly create the right rows and bind them.
- Override areAllItemsEnabled() and return false.
- Override isEnabled() and if the position is a separator, return false.

Then one way of doing it is to have a separate list of only the header items then creating a method like this to check the item type for all the methods mentioned above.

```
public Boolean isSeparator(int position) {
    if (separatorList.contains(getItem(position)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```