# How to use SimpleCursorAdapter that has separator in ListView? Android

Tags: android, listview

Hi I'm trying to create a ListView that has separator or header that looks like below using the SimpleCursorAdapter

[image]

my data is from my local database that's why i i tried using SimpleCursorAdapter  but i'm having difficulties creating the header 
by using my header it will separate the activities by its day

I create a separate layout.xml for my header and another layout.xml file for my items_list

here is my code

```
public class List_of_Activities extends Fragment {

DBHelper dbHelper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
private SimpleCursorAdapter headerAdapter;

String[] details = new String[] {
        DBHelper.KEY_TITLE,
        DBHelper.KEY_TIME
};

String[] header_column = new String[] {DBHelper.KEY_DISPLAY};

// the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
int[] to = new int[] {
        R.id.title,
        R.id.desc,
};

int[] header_to = new int[] {
        R.id.header,

};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_programme, container, false);

    initialazeDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getDetailsItems();
    Cursor header_cursor = dbHelper.getDayHeader();

    headerAdapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_item_layout, header_cursor, header_column, header_to, 0);
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter( getActivity(), R.layout.text_list_item_layout, cursor, columns, to, 0);


    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    return v;
}
```

in my code it only shows the details. How can i combined them?

can anyone give me an idea on how to do this? or a sample code for it? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Use a `CursorAdapter`, doing this would be much simpler. Read about the `getView()` method in particular.

Comment: thank you.. can you give me an example for it?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865197/listview-separators-using-a-cursoradapter) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261593/custom-listview-with-date-as-sectionheader-used-custom-simplecursoradapter) the latter being an example for SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: simply use expandable list view

Comment: is there any other way to do it?